# ScreenShot of the Root Layout i.e Scroll View

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing a GPA Calculator application. For that purpose, I want to install some features related to capturing the screenshot of the final activity where the user will see the subjects and their marks and GPA etc. 
My root view is **ScrollView** Layout *(all the contents i.e subjects their marks)* and wants to capture it. 
I tried the following code but the code works fine only for the single view

```
 Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(text1.getWidth() , text1.getHeight() , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                bitmap.setDensity(text1.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap) ;
                text1.draw(canvas);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

But if I try the same code for the Parent View i.e Scroll View it gives Exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

I want to Capture the whole Scroll View  And save it to Internal Drive !! Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 while loading Bitmap from View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605662/illegalargumentexception-width-and-height-must-be-0-while-loading-bitmap-from)

Comment: Please refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817116/take-a-full-screenshot-of-scrollview-android

Comment: @SivakumarS thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use the drawingcache instead

Hope this helps

```
text1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap=text1.getDrawingCache();
```